# Data binding directly to a store query

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework

I am trying to group amount and load into a drop down box in vb.net (asp.net)

But I get the following error:

Data binding directly to a store query (DbSet, DbQuery, DbSqlQuery, DbRawSqlQuery) is not supported. Instead populate a DbSet with data, for example by calling Load on the DbSet, and then bind to local data. For WPF bind to DbSet.Local. For WinForms bind to DbSet.Local.ToBindingList(). For ASP.NET WebForms you can bind to the result of calling ToList() on the query or use Model Binding, for more information see

**My Code:**

```
'Load Amounts
Dim SourceAmounts = (From p In db.PayoutAdjustments
                     Order By p.Amount
                     Where p.PayoutId = PayoutId
                     Group p By Key = p.Amount Into Group
                     Select Amount = Group)

cmbAmount.DataSource = SourceAmounts
cmbAmount.DataTextField = "Amount"
cmbAmount.DataValueField = "Amount"
cmbAmount.DataBind()
cmbAmount.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Select Amount", 0))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to execute the query before data binding. Using ToList() will force your query to execute.

```
cmbAmount.DataSource = SourceAmounts.ToList()
```

Comment: Of course.....now I get another error. DataBinding: 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[CommissionsEFModels.PayoutAdjustment, CommissionsEFModels, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' does not contain a property with the name 'Amount'.

Comment: I think you need to change the Select part of your linq query. Did you mean to use (Select Group)? What output are you expecting?

Comment: Just the amount field grouped